# Why does the Canvas.FillText method seem to use the wrong coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am rendering text onto a HTML-Canvas like so:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FMSIQUFFO5PL

As you can see, the text is supposed to be rendered at 32, 32. But for some reasons, the string appears too high.

It this because the Canvas' coordinates start at the top left corner of the Canvas-Element and the String's coordinates at the lower left corner of the String?

How do I work around this issue so that I can render text at exactly the position I am expecting it to be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default the vertical text-alignment (baseline) is set to "alphabetic" which uses the general bottom of the text for the y coordinate.

[image: alphabetic]

You can change this behavior by setting [`textBaseline`](https://devdocs.io/dom/canvasrenderingcontext2d/textbaseline) to "top".

[image: top]

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "32px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";   // change baseline property
ctx.fillText("Hello World", 32, 32);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Comment: When used `strokeText()` the outline still shows outside of the starting point.